# Reg: How to reflect cell value to formula cell using apache POI

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am pretty new to automation and i  have a scenario where i need to automate excel sheet using apache POI

I have a balancing sheet with some pre-defined formulas in it.

I need to get the data from UI application and store it in a map.
Later,i need to access an excel file and input the data in some cell(example:B3),the next cell contains the formula(C3) [Formula is '=Value(B3)'], which will store the same value(B3 value) in C3.

I have designed the code, which is inserting the data at cell B3,but, the same value is not reflecting in C3.

Note: When i do the same process manually i.e. when i input some value in B3, automatically the value in reflecting in C3.

Observation: The same is not happening in automation.

Request to help me with some logic, which i can use and implement in my solution.

PFA screenshot for your reference[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ornT6.png)

Comment: Can you provide the code so far?

Comment: [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html)!